# Global name error while using requests module

Tags: python, python-requests

I have Python package "testPackage" that contains two files functions.py and mainFunction.py. (I am using Python 2.7 on Anaconda distribution)

**functions.py** contains the following psuedo code:

```
import requests

def myfunction():
  req = requests.get(....)
```

**mainFunction.py** calls this functions as follows:

```
import os
os.chdir('path/to/the/package/')

from testPackage import *

def main():
  result = myfunction(...)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
NameError: global name 'requests' is not defined
```

Why am I getting this error since I have already imported the requests module in the corresponding module?

Comment: Can you provide more of the traceback and actual code? There isn't enough here to help you.

Comment: Have you made sure that the `requests` package installed? (`pip install requests`) ?

Comment: @BorrajaX that would result in an ImportError, not a NameError. It seems far more likely that OP is not actually importing requests but without more information there's nothing to do but speculate

Comment: Thanks for both of your help...Looks like my IPython notebook behaved weirdly...after closing/reopening IPython, running the same code worked fine

Comment: @sigmavirus24, You're absolutely right... *The day I learn to read, I'll conquer the world* **:-D**